# C program to print its own address space?

Tags: c, linux, proc, systems-programming

I read `cat /proc/[pid]/maps` gives the informaion about its address space.
So I want to write a program which will print its own address space.

My program is this;

```
  pid_t pid;
  int fd;
  char *buf;

  pid = getpid();

  fd = open("/proc/????/maps", O_RDONLY);
```

I'm getting the PID, but it won't help me to open the file.
How to convert the pid from `pid_t` to string and add it to `open` call?

Or is there any other way to open the file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All modern procfs systems implement `"/proc/self/"` for the running process. Just

```
fd = open("/proc/self/maps", O_RDONLY);
```

If you still wish to create the path string yourself then you have to use `sprintf`

```
char filename[128];
sprintf(filename, "/proc/%d/maps", getpid());
fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
```

Comment: but i want to use only API's

Comment: @SGG I don't get that question. What APIs do you want to use?

Comment: sprintf is c funcion. Is there any API for that?

Comment: @SGG - what's your idea of an API?  Stick the above code in a function, add some error checking, and shazaam, you have an API.

Comment: @SGG As I wrote above your easiest way is to just open `/proc/self/maps` which is a symlink to the calling processes `/proc/pid`. `sprintf` function is part of the C standard and is found in `stdio.h`. It will come with every `libc` which also contains `open` and the other functions you need to actually read that file.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to print mapping information for review, one simple method:

**you can use [system](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) library call to execute `cat /proc/[pid]/maps`**

A simple C code is as follows:

```
char command[256];
sprintf(command, "cat /proc/%d/maps", getpid());
system(command);
```

You can refer to one example in my [Gist](https://gist.github.com/mudongliang/4453997e6c6258b1794e4b6ab73fd8a6).

Comment: This does not give anything the earlier comment did not have. Using system() is lazy and bad form. Being inefficient is least of its problems. It can be affected by number of outside factors causing unexpected behavior and side effects, including being more open for exploit. And unless you do it right, it can for example eat your SIGINT (Ctrl-C).